# Why can I not compare this string array ITEM to a string?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, collections, comparison, operators

```
StreamReader srr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("saved"));    
string[] slist = srr.ReadToEnd().Split('}');
                        System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection clist = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
                        for (int i = 0; i < slist.Length; i++) {
                            if (slist[i].Trim != "") // ERROR IS HERE
                            {
                                clist.Add(slist[i]);
                            }
                        }
```

From another section of my program I'm saving the current list of files in the clipboard to a file, and doing that by seperating each path with "}" so kind of like ( C:}D:}C:\Windows\Media} ). Then here, I am opening the file, splitting it into a string array then i need to check wether the each path is an empty string but visual studio says "Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'string'". I am not comparing the string array directly to the string though (`slist[i]`) so what is causing this, is it just a problem with VS or am i missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call Trim(): `if(slist[i].Trim() != "")`

Comment: Any time you see a complaint about a method group, it means you forgot parentheses.

Comment: ok, noted thanks :) , that probably just prevented like 20 future SO questions :D